# Running a statement based on information from POST variable

Tags: php

I'm in a bit of pickle but the answer is probably pretty simple.

So I have my POST variable:

```
 Array ( [accept] => accept,29 [accept1] => accept,30 [submit] => Save Selections )
```

That's just a print_r of $_POST.

Basically what I want to do is get the first variable, remove the 'accept,' part and store the number next to it in a variable, run some MySQL queries using that variable (containing that number) then move onto the next one; removing the 'accept,' storing the number next to it and running a query using that stored number. It want to do this for as many times is necessary to go through all the elements containing 'accept,' then a number.

Any help would be appreciated.

I was playing around with some ideas and have this code. It obviously doesn't work but perhaps I could fix and build on it?

```
    while($i <= $elements)
    {
        while($x == 1)
        {
            $id = explode(',', next($_POST));
            echo $id;
            $x = 0;
        }
        $i++;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Im not sure this would fix your problem but I hope this helps and gives you an idea:

```
$i = 0;
while($i <= count($your_array))
{
    $your_var = substr($your_array[$i], 7, 2); //get the number from your accept,29
    $query = "SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE COLUMN = ". $your_var; //use it to run queries as you said
    $i+=1;
}
```

**UPDATE** - Im not sure if this would work

```
foreach($your_post_array as $items)
{
    $your_var = substr($items, 7, 2);
    $query = "SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE COLUMN = ". $your_var; //use it to run queries as you said
    $i+=1;
}
```

**Maybe you should try to echo first the variables to make sure**
 `echo $your_var = substr($items, 7, 2);`

Comment: Thank you! The first one works. At first it didn't but was because I forgot my POST array was now multidimensional so I wasn't referencing the elements correctly :) Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I would use a `foreach` loop to loop through `$_POST`, check if the key starts with `accept` ([`stripos`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stripos.php)?), explode the value if it does and get the second value of the found array and store that somewhere for later use.

By the way, if possible I would change the front-end so that you have just one variable (an array) in `$_POST` you have to loop through.